# Java TimerTask to timeout after sometime

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, scheduling, timertask

I have a timerTask that runs periodically, but sometimes it gets stuck (doesn't fail or give any exception).

Hence, the next iteration of this task doesn't start as the previous one is stuck.

I want the task to :

1. Either TIMEOUT after some time (so that next iteration can begin).
2. Or the next iteration to begin even if previous is running, and that forcefully cancels any previous running task.

Below is my code :

```
    private static Timer timer = new Timer();

    private static TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try{
                aSeparateMethodWhichGetsStuckOccasionally();

            }catch (Exception exception){
                logger.info(">>> Exception : " + exception);
            }

        }
    };
    
    public static void scheduleTask() {
        
        initialDelay = 600000;
        gap = 600000;

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, initialDelay, gap);
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you get down to reasons your tasks get stuck and address them instead of piling ever more stuff in there to also potentially get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

First, you must write `aSeparateMethodWhichGetsStuckOccasionally()` so that it can respond properly to interrupts.  Interrupts are the only way to stop many operations.

If that method is catching `InterruptedException`, remove the try/catch entirely, and add `throws InterruptedException` to the method declaration.  If that method contains any `catch (Exception)` clauses, you must either check for `InterruptedException` and terminate in such a case, or better, change the clause to only catch the exceptions you absolutely need to catch, not including InterruptedException.  (Catching `Exception` is a bad practice.  Most unchecked exceptions exist to expose programmer mistakes, which should be corrected rather than hidden.  NullPointerException and IndexOutOfBoundsException are examples of such exceptions.)

This will make it possible to interrupt the method.  You can then use [ExecutorService.invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) to enforce a timeout on it:

```
private static final ExecutorService executor =
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public static TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            Callable<Void> subtask = () -> {
                aSeparateMethodWhichGetsStuckOccasionally();
                return null;
            };

            List<Future<Void>> futures =
                executor.invokeAll(Collections.singleton(subtask),
                    gap, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

            Future<?> future = futures.get(0);
            if (!future.isCancelled()) {
                // Check if subtask threw an exception.
                future.get();
            }

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, ">>> Exception: " + exception, exception);
        }
    }
};
```